# Compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta }d\theta $ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, parametrization

I want to compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta }d\theta $ using the change of variable $z=\exp(i\theta)$.

Using the change of variable, we would get $\int \frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta }d\theta = -\frac{1}{i}\int \frac{2-z^n-z^{-n}}{\left (z-1  \right )^2}dz$

I've seen answers for this problem using the singularity of $1$, but at this moment, I haven't learned about the singularity, so I wanted to use the corollary that we can get

> $f^{(n)}(w)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma }\frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{n+1}}dz$
> as a result. As you know, we need some conditions to use this
> corollary such as 1. $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic,
> and 2. $z_0 \in \Omega$ and $r>0$ must satisfy $w \in
>  \overline{B(z_0,r)}\subset \Omega $. 3. $\gamma : [0,1]\rightarrow
>  \Omega$ is given by $\gamma (t)=w+r\exp(2\pi i t)$.

It seems like I can use this corollary, if we let $\Omega = \mathbb{C} \setminus\left \{ 0 \right \}$, $z_0 = 1$, $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

However, what I am really having trouble with is $\gamma $, since the corollary needs $[0,1]$ while I need $[0,2\pi]$.

I first ignored $[0,1]$ and just set $\gamma :[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\left \{ 0 \right \}$ s.t $\gamma (t)=1+\frac{1}{2}\exp(2\pi i t)$.

So, I could get $0$ as desired. I wonder if this is just a coincidence.

If so, how should I reparametrize the path $\gamma$?

If not, does that mean we can use any domain for the path $\gamma $ like I did in my solution when we use this corollary?

Comment: Must you use the substitution? There's a much slicker way that is almost elementary and avoids complex integration, if you're interested.

Comment: @Integrand Yes, the problem wants me to use the substitution.

Comment: That's a bummer.

Comment: @Integrand Yeah, but if the corollary is useful for solving this problem, I believe there won't be anything messy that causes some headaches.

Comment: I'd be interested in the alternative solution if someone wants to present it secondarily along with the substitution.

Comment: In your corollary (which is Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives) it does not matter how $\gamma$ is parametrized, at long as it surrounds the point $w$ once in positive direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta }d\theta$ does not change its value if $n$ is replaced by $-n$, so it suffices to compute the integral for the case $n \ge 0$.

For $z \ne 0, 1$ is
$$
-\frac{2-z^n-z^{-n}}{(z-1)^2} = \frac{(z^n-1)^2}{z^n (z-1)^2}
= \frac{(1+z+z^2+ \cdots z^{n-1})^2}{z^n}
$$
So the only singularity of the integrand is at $z=0$, and we have
$$
I_n = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta }d\theta
= \frac 1i \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^n} \, dz
$$
where $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$, and
$$
f(z) = (1+z+z^2+ \cdots z^{n-1})^2 \\
 = 1 + 2z + \cdots + n z^{n-1} + \cdots + z^{2n-2}
$$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$.

Using your corollary (which is Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives) it follows that
$$
 I_n = 2 \pi \frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!} = 2 \pi n \, .
$$

The answer for arbitrary integers $n \in \Bbb Z $ is $I_n = 2 \pi|n|$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my alternative solution, which doesn't satisfy OP's requirement of using contour integration.

Using induction and angle-addition, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (the case $n$ negative is identical because cosine is even and the case $n=0$ is trivial) we have
$$
1-\cos(n\theta) = (1-\cos(\theta))\left(n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k \cos((n-k)\theta)\right)
$$Now the integration is trivial: the cosine terms integrate to zero and the answer is clearly $2\pi |n|$.

Comment: There is actually a direct relationship between your trigonometric identity and the calculation which I used for the contour integration: With $z=e^{it}$ is $$\frac{1-\cos(n\theta )}{1-\cos\theta } = \frac{z^{-n}(z^n-1)^2}{z^{-1}(z-1)^2} = \frac{(1+z+z^2+ \cdots z^{n-1})^2}{z^{n-1}} = n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(z^{n-k} + z^{k-n})\, .$$

Comment: Thanks for that insight and your solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Your solution is fine as well, I just wanted to point out the connection. (Which one finds “slicker” depends on the background :)